# Replace one data point in data frame

Tags: r

I want to insert each of these values into the the data frame, the following values are just an example. I need to be able to reference each cell for each data input as I want to use it with a loop to save the output. I tried using this example, but it doesn't seem to work consistently.
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/change-value-in-one-cell-td3589456.html

```
  Distances <- data.frame( "Main.Point" = numeric(0), "Sub.Point" = numeric(0), "Distance" = numeric(0))

### Save to Distances Data.Frame ###
E<-nrow(Distances)+1
E
Distances[E,"Sub.Point"]<-nRuns
Distances[E,"Main.Point"]<-NRuns
Distances[E,"Distance"]<-D
```

When I run it, only Sub Point works, the others get these errors

```
> Distances[E,"Sub.Point"]<-nRuns
> Distances[E,"Main.Point"]<-NRuns
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 3123) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> Distances[E,"Distance"]<-D
Error in match(value, lx) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Comment: Just use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `data.frame` definition: `Distances <- data.frame( "Main.Point" = character(0), 
                         "Sub.Point" = integer(0), 
                         "Distance" = character(0), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: or try `rbind(Distances, c(nRuns, NRuns, D))`